# How to combine columns for DatatextFiled of DropdownList?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have Dropdown list of Faculty Name.
In my database they are stored as FirstName, LastName, MiddleName,

I want to combine it in dropdownlist

```
ViewData["FacultyID"] = new SelectList(faculty, "ID", "FirstName");
```

at place of datatextfield.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ViewData["FacultyID"] = 
   new SelectList(faculty.Select(f=> new 
   {id= f.Id, Name = f.Firstname + f.LastName}), "ID", "Name");
```

Comment: It's simple but great answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could change your sql query:

```
SELECT ..., COALESCE(FirstName + ' ' + MiddleName + ' ' + LastName) as FullName,...
```